# Can you call functions using the arrow keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arrow-functions

I'm trying to make a golf game in which when the user presses the left or right arrow, an actual arrow will aim to where you have suggested it should. Then the ball will be released by a press of the space bar and roll away, hoping to be captured in the golf hole. It's not that that's troubling me though, it's the first part; the aiming of the arrows.
I have made 10 different functions that point in different directions but the problem is the user interaction. I need to make the arrows (functions) go by the arrow keys. I have named the functions like so:

```
one_one
one_two
one_three
```

and so on. How do I call them and erase the last one but, more importantly, make that process go repeatedly?
Thanks in advance!
P.S I'm using Python-3 and on VS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop; the `keyboard` module uses event-triggered activation rather than polling.

```
import keyboard

def on_left_arrow(e):
    print('Hello World')

keyboard.on_press_key("left", on_left_arrow)
```

For the second part of your question, you could hold the directions in a 'queue';

```
directions = ['N', 'E', 'W', 'S']

def on_left_arrow(e):
    # pop the first item out of the list 
    current = direction.pop(0)

    # move it to the end
    directions = directions.append(current)

    print(current) 

def on_right_arrow(e):
    # pop the last item
    current = direction.pop()

    # move it to the beginning
    directions = directions.insert(0, current)

    print(current)
```

Please note that the `keyboard` library requires `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to make this happen repeatedly. If I were to continue pressing the left arrow in my case, I would get the same arrow again and again. How would I change it to the next? And what if the user presses the right arrow? Then I would need to make it go backwards as well.